# Permission denied for a root to lookup a token in Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I logged to vault with a root token.

I try to

```
$ vault token lookup
```

but I keep getting

```
Error looking up token: Error making API request.

URL: GET https://106.120.137.192:8200/v1/auth/token/lookup-self
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied
```

I have vault logs on Trace level, but there is no related event.

I enabled audit logs to see what's going on but they give me no hint.

```json
[
  {
    "time": "2021-10-21T15:34:17.647568529Z",
    "type": "request",
    "auth": {
      "token_type": "default"
    },
    "request": {
      "id": "1d5d7f5f-94ca-e281-c0b2-5ffbceccb0dc",t
      "operation": "read",
      "mount_type": "token",
      "client_token": "hmac-sha256:75f6fc0b19c105af0f2c27fd180742eef282c38d346fc732771bfaa2d1ce2ea6",
      "namespace": {
        "id": "root"
      },
      "path": "auth/token/lookup-self",
      "remote_address": "172.18.0.1"
    },
    "error": "permission denied"
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-10-21T15:34:17.647692649Z",
    "type": "response",
    "auth": {
      "token_type": "default"
    },
    "request": {
      "id": "1d5d7f5f-94ca-e281-c0b2-5ffbceccb0dc",
      "operation": "read",
      "mount_type": "token",
      "client_token": "hmac-sha256:75f6fc0b19c105af0f2c27fd180742eef282c38d346fc732771bfaa2d1ce2ea6",
      "namespace": {
        "id": "root"
      },
      "path": "auth/token/lookup-self",
      "remote_address": "172.18.0.1"
    },
    "response": {
      "mount_type": "token",
      "data": {
        "error": "hmac-sha256:9493ed1bac12e9a7fae0e03c488dd1d5f46bcc33ea36ee2c1e5ca92acd683c81"
      }
    },
    "error": "1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"
  }
]
```

What else can I do?

I am running Vault 1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the problem does not happen when I am running same command on localhost, i.e., against local instance of Vault.